# Why is "macro expansion to text a lossy process"?

Tags: rust, rust-macros

As disclaimed in the disclaimer section of `cargo-expand`'s readme https://github.com/dtolnay/cargo-expand#disclaimer.

Also, are there any guidelines that can be followed when writing/using macros that make the process less lossy/more likely that the output compiles?

Also, is there potential that the situation will improve in the future, or is this a really fundamental limitation?

Answer (score 4):

Because of hygiene.

When you write the identifier `foo` in source code, and there are multiple `foo`s existing, there are clear rules which one you're referencing (the scoping rules). But with macros these rules can break sometimes.

For instance:

```rust
fn main() {
    let foo = 123;
    macro_rules! foo {
        () => { foo };
    }
    let foo = 456;
    println!("{}", foo!());
}
```

If we expand this code we get (I didn't expand the `println!()`):

```rust
fn main() {
    let foo = 123;
    let foo = 456;
    println!("{}", foo);
}
```

But this code *doesn't produce the same result as the original code*. It prints `456`, while the original code prints `123`.

This is because the identifier `foo` inside the macro `foo!()` refers to *a specific `foo`*. And this `foo` isn't the same `foo` we would resolve to if we would write the bare identifier `foo`.

> Also, are there any guidelines that can be followed when writing/using macros that make the process less lossy/more likely that the output compiles?

I don't see why you would need that. Macro expansion isn't meant to be reversed, and it's unclear to me why you would ever want to run the macro-expanded code. Often it will also not run because of other reasons, such as private items of std (for example, if I would expand the `println!()` it wouldn't compile).

> Also, is there potential that the situation will improve in the future, or is this a really fundamental limitation?

I don't think it will "improve" simply because I don't think anybody cares about changing the current situation, and changing it is not clearly an improvement. But if you really want, you can expand the code with `rustc -Zunpretty=expanded,hygiene`. The resulting code is lossless representation of the original code, but it is not a valid Rust.

Comment: hmm, if this is the only issue, it seems like there could easily be a `rustc -Zunpretty=expanded,hygiene_rename` which produces lossless, valid rust code at the expense of renaming macro-introduced names (which rustc can definitely already keep straight when it compiles normally). but sure, maybe no one cares

Comment: As a Rustacean who has also worked in Common Lisp, I can confidently say macro hygiene is a good thing. If you have unhygienic macros, you just have to constantly `(gensym)` up fresh symbol names to avoid shadowing. It constantly shoots me in the foot, and I can't think of a single time that the *lack* of hygiene worked in my favor.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @ChayimFriedman's answer, there's two more things that get lost mentioned [in the proc_macro2 docs](https://docs.rs/proc-macro2/latest/proc_macro2/struct.TokenStream.html#impl-Display-for-TokenStream):

- Spans are lost, i.e. the information which lines and characters in the original source file a token came from.
- Macro expansion creates token groups (Just like `{` and `}` does), but with an empty delimiter. Those empty delimiter token groups don't appear in strings. However, I can't come up with an example where this makes a difference, [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=eef1a5b46ae02eaec4a14340e15bb6a7) does not work. You may have to write your own macro crate to feel the effect of this.